# How to trigger handle_event function using quantum in Phoenix LiveView

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I have a Quantum ([Quantum is a cron job style code scheduler and module for Elixir](https://hexdocs.pm/quantum/readme.html)) timed event and I want to perform the actions inside of a LiveView handle_event function each minute. The handle_event function takes three arguments and they are not available in the config page. I can't pass arguments that don't exist.

In short, how do I do what this code is trying to perform:

**config.ex**
**Quantum code:**

```
config :app, App.Scheduler,
  jobs: [
    # Every minute
    {"* * * * *",      {AppWeb.PageLive, :handle_event, ["add"]}}, 
 
  ]
```

**Module code**

```
defmodule AppWeb.PageLive do
   use AppWeb, :live_view 
   alias App.Periodically
   def mount(_params, _session, socket)  do

     {:ok, assign(socket, run_timer: 0)} 

   end
   

   def handle_event("add",_params, socket) do 
    
     {:noreply, assign(socket, run_timer: socket.assigns.run_timer + 1)}
    end

   def render(assigns) do

       ~H"""
            <%= assigns.run_timer %>
            <.button phx-click="add">Add</.button>
       """ 
   end

end
```

The code above increments a counter when a button is clicked. I want to use Quantum to trigger the handle_event internals in general - it could be doing anything. I created a working spike test that runs other functions, just not the specific event I want.

The App.Scheduler code is here:

```
defmodule App.Scheduler do
  use Quantum, otp_app: :app
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One cannot get to the internal process state from outside this process, this is the core abstraction on top of [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) actor model.

Instead, one should send messages to the process, and `LiveView` provides both [`handle_call/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#c:handle_call/3) and [`handle_cast/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#c:handle_cast/2) callbacks.

That said, you implement `handle_cast/2` and from within its context, where you have `socket` at fingers, you might directly call `handle_event/3`.